# How to skip a cypress test in beforeeach hook?

Tags: cypress

I want to skip and allow tests in the before each hook as follows

```js
beforeEach(() =>{
  if(Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.title === `Skip this`){
     // skip the first test case only but run the second one [How?]
  }
});

it(`Skip this`, () => {

});

it(`Don't skip this`, () => {

});
```

In the place of [How?] I tried using the following:

1. `cy.skipOn(true)` from the cypress ***skip-test*** plugin but apparently it skips the beforeEach hook not the test itself.
2. `this.skip()` but apparently this is not a valid function. Also, if I changed the beforeEach from an arrow function expression, the skip function works but it skips the whole suite and not just the desired test case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the function type from arrow function to **regular function**, then you can use the built-in Mocha `skip()` method.

```js
beforeEach(function() {
  if (condition) {
    this.skip()
  }
})
```

---

Your code sample will look like this:

```js
beforeEach(function() {     // NOTE regular function

  if (Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.title === 'Skip this') {
    this.skip()
  }
});

it(`Skip this`, () => {

});

it(`Don't skip this`, () => {

});
```

---

Or use the **Mocha context** you already use for test title

```js
beforeEach(() => {        // NOTE arrow function is allowed

  const ctx = Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx

  if (ctx.currentTest.title === 'Skip this') {
    ctx.skip()
  }
});
```

[image]

---

**afterEach()**

If you have an `afterEach()` hook, the `this.skip()` call does not stop it running for the skipped test.

You should check the condition inside that hook also,

```js
afterEach(function() {
  if (condition) return;

  ...  // code that should not run for skipped tests.
})
```

Comment: I have tried this, but this makes the whole describe block skip not just the it block. I have added another example in the question.

Comment: If your `if()` condition is correct it will work. Have you checked if `Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.title === "Skip this"` evaluates correctly?

Comment: Yes, I checked that it evaluates correctly, and this.skip() apparently skips all the subsequent test case in the test suite and just the current test case.

Comment: It is working now. The problem was that I had an afterEach hook that missed up things. The solution was to guard my afterEach function with an if condition. Can you kindly add that to your answer so that it would help other people?